# Trouble with creating bar & pie subplot with R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I've created a Plotly bar and pie chart and want to combine them to form one chart.

When I use subplot() to combine these Plotly charts, the pie & bar charts overlap.

Any advice on how to present these plots so that each is in its own row? Thank you.

Here's a picture of what I'm currently experiencing:
[image]

Reprex below:

```
#Pie chart example
pie_tibble <- tibble(donuts = c(49050, 66924),
                    group = c("Group A", "Group B"))

pie <- plot_ly(data = pie_tibble, labels = ~group, values = ~donuts, type = 'pie',
               showlegend = F,
               hoverinfo = "none",
               marker = ~list(colors = c('#404040', '#24608B'))) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))


bar_tibble <- tibble(category = c("Cat 1", "Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 2"),
                     pct_increase = c(0.17, 0.25, 0.64, 0.85),
                     week = c(1, 2, 1, 2)) 

#Bar chart example
bar <- plot_ly(data = bar_tibble, hoverinfo = "none") %>%
  
  layout(
    barmode = 'stack',
    showlegend = F) %>%
  
  add_trace(
    x = ~pct_increase,
    y = ~category,
    type = "bar",
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = "aggregate",
        groups = ~category,
        aggregations = list(
          list(
            target = "x", func = "avg", enabled = T)))))
 
#Combine charts
subplot(bar, pie, nrows = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pie charts and `plotly::subplot()` are notoriously challenging - though you can get around many of the issues by specifying the domain manually. Below I have changed the `pie` code by specifying the `domain = list(...)` as so:

```
pie <- plot_ly(data = pie_tibble, labels = ~group, values = ~donuts, type = 'pie',
               # Specify the domain here
               domain = list(x = c(0.5, 0.5), # centered on x axis
                             y = c(0.0, 0.4)),
               showlegend = F,
               hoverinfo = "none",
               marker = ~list(colors = c('#404040', '#24608B'))) %>% 
   layout(xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

`subplot(bar, pie, nrows = 2)` now gives:

[image]

Sorry I don't have a more elegant answer, but hoping someone else might!

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful to know. I have the charts connected to a crosstalk filter in a flexdashboard. The chart positioning is good when the filter is set to the default selection. However, when I filter to another category, the positioning defaults to the overlapping position. Any thoughts on how to avoid this?

Comment: Hmmm this might be beyond my skillset - You may want to post this specific issue as a new question so someone smarter than me can answer!